# Clickhouse query with a LIMIT clause inefficiently reads too many rows

Tags: clickhouse

I'm querying Clickhouse with a query that has ORDER BY and LIMIT 1, and the ORDER BY matches the table's sort order. The query returns 1 row as expected, however, 50+ rows were scanned to return the result.

I would expect ClickHouse to scan only 1 row as the ORDER BY is in the table's sort order. What's happening here and what can I do to fix this?

```
SELECT * FROM comp_intel_scrapes
order by
    client_slug,
    client_hotel_id,
    argset_id, 
    scrape_datetime,
    preferred_country,
    preferred_currency,
    adults, 
    children,
    nights,
    min_checkin_date,
    max_checkin_date
limit 1   

----

Elapsed: 0.004s
Read: 54 rows (8.84KB)
```

By the way, Clickhouse.com's cloud is being used here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a table engine.
Primary index is sparse https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/improving-query-performance/sparse-primary-indexes/sparse-primary-indexes-design/

Because of this CH is unable to read less than one granule ~8192 rows.